# VS2012 C++ Win32 - Color Messed up

Tags: c++, colors, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, win32-process

I am just starting to write some C++ code using VS2012 (update 1). I have worked with VS products for years using C#, but with C++ syntax I am experiencing weird highlight color:

[Images sample http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/409/67556947.png](http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/409/67556947.png)

Code is compiling without errors (forget about the warnings), but to be honest it's really weird. I am using no extension\plugin. It happens very often and I haven't found a procedure to get rid of it.

System specs:
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64
RAM: 8 GB

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709
Installed Version: Ultimate

Comment: What are your system specs?

Comment: Updated in the main post

Comment: did you try devenv /resetsettings ?

Comment: I haven't. Rebooting VS 2012 fix the issue, but it's happen really very often...